# Hiding divs in parent's overflow?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent holder with `overflow:hidden;`, inside I have blocks, I wish to "hide" some of these in the parent's overflow.

For example:

```
...| from here these are hidden off page

[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

Above I just want the first block to be on screen and the others to be in the hidden overflow.

I've tried using:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden
}
.child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But the children just bunch up and stay on screen.

Comment: can you please share the code of what you have achieved so far and where you are stuck and need help

Comment: you need to put your code question is too vague. `Overflow: hidden` generally applies to text-content normally

Comment: code is now in question

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width for the parent (visible width), and add a wrapper inside it with a bigger width (visible + hidden width)...try this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: grey;
}
.container {
  width: calc(3 * (200px - 20px));
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.child {
  width: calc(200px - 2 * 20px);
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The container won't overflow unless there is some kind of limit on its dimensions. Try setting the `max-height` or `max-width` property.

```
.parent
{
    max-height: 30em; /* replace with the expected height of .child */
    max-width: 30em; /* or max-width if you're trying to get horizontal overflow */
}
```

Also, why did you set `.parent` to have `display: flex`? With no other settings, this will just cause all of its children to display side by side and divide up the horizontal space.

If you want the children to be able to overflow, then remove this.